# Javascript global namespace and dynamic property question 

Tags: javascript

Say I want to have a global object which can be visible and accessible across pages(??)

```
// core.js
var MyLib = {}; // global Object cointainer
MyLib.value = 1;
```

If I define this way, then I can have access to MyLib.value in other places as long as I load the `core.js`.

However, if I want to add new property to object `MyLib` in somewhere else, say:

```
//extra.js
MyLib.otherVal = 2;
```

Then I try to access `MyLib.otherVal` from a different place, it is not available. I probably have some fundamental misunderstanding on how this suppose to work. I hope someone can enlighten me.

**After reading the comments, I realized the scope I want is indeed across pages. Is that even possible?**

thanks

Oliver

Comment: What do you mean by "from a different place"? Are you including both files?

Comment: If you mean on another page - that is how it is supposed to behave. Reloading/navigating to a web page clears all JavaScript memory (variables etc.).

Comment: It definitely will work if **1.** you import "core.js" **before** "extra.js", and **2.** all your references in "other places" are in the same page in scripts executed **after** the first two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to carry data across pages, there are really three major methods:

1. **LocalStorage**. See [this page](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) for a fairly thorough explanation of the concept, how to use it, and so forth. [Here](http://www.jstorage.info/) is a library dealing with JavaScript storage.
2. **Cookies**. Cookies can store 4KiB of data, but some users disable them.
3. **`window.name`**. You can store up to 2MiB of data in `window.name`. [Here](http://www.thomasfrank.se/sessionvars.html) is a library that focuses on storing data in `window.name`; it seems fairly well-written.

You could potentially write an app to take advantage of all three of these techniques, starting with LocalStorage and falling back to `window.name` if all else fails.